# How can I find the parameters of a wsdl service in c#

Tags: c#, wsdl, soapui, service-reference

I am trying to get all parameters,methods etc of a wsdl service which there is no documentation.
The web page of the wsdl service is:

[https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicisnet/MessageProcessorService?wsdl](https://www2.gsis.gr/wsicisnet/MessageProcessorService?wsdl)

I found that in
https://www1.gsis.gr/wsicisnet/MessageProcessorService?xsd=3

there are some attributes that are required

```
<xs:attribute name="traderID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="wsUserID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="wsPass" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
```

but when I try to send the message it gives me an error

> RulesConditionasError: SubmittingTraderIdentification
> ([SubmittingTraderIdentification: null]  must be the same as the
> trader ID (801063350)

I can't find anywhere any attribute or parameter for SubmittingTraderIdentification .
Can someone help me out?

EDIT:
When I load the wsdl service in SoapUI and generate a request it look like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:icis="http://icis.externaldomain.services.ws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <icis:processIncomingMessageRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <icis:messageRequest traderID="?" wsUserID="?" wsPass="?">
            <DigitallySignedMessage messageType="?" isXmlString="?">
               <xmlMessage>?</xmlMessage>
            </DigitallySignedMessage>
         </icis:messageRequest>
      </icis:processIncomingMessageRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

EDIT 2:
This is the XML that I try send from my program:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EF15A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Header>
        <MessageSender>TRADER.GR</MessageSender>
        <MessageRecipient>NES.EL</MessageRecipient>
        <DateOfPreparation>2020-10-06</DateOfPreparation>
        <TimeOfPreparation>16:30:00</TimeOfPreparation>
        <MessageIdentifier>20/198</MessageIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <DeclarationOfExciseTaxesRegistration>
            <SubmittingOperator>
                <SubmittingOperatorIdentification>1234567</SubmittingOperatorIdentification>
                <SubmittingTraderIdentification>1234567</SubmittingTraderIdentification>
            </SubmittingOperator>
            <ExciseTaxesDeclaration>
                <LocalReferenceNumber>1544237495/20/198</LocalReferenceNumber>
                <Fallbackflag>0</Fallbackflag>
                <RegistrationOffice>GR004531</RegistrationOffice>
                <DocumentState>0</DocumentState>
                <DocumentNumber>1</DocumentNumber>
                <TotalDocuments>1</TotalDocuments>
                <NumberOfRows>1</NumberOfRows>
                <DispatchCountry>BG</DispatchCountry>
                <DestinationCountry>GR</DestinationCountry>
                <ExistenceOfContainerFlag>0</ExistenceOfContainerFlag>
                <DeliveryConditions>FCA</DeliveryConditions>
                <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                <InvoiceAmount>6600.00</InvoiceAmount>
                <ExchangeFactor>1</ExchangeFactor>
                <ChemicalAnalysisPerformedFlag>0</ChemicalAnalysisPerformedFlag>
                <ThroughSimplifiedProcedureFlag>0</ThroughSimplifiedProcedureFlag>
                <PaymentMethodCode>H</PaymentMethodCode>
                <CertificateIssuanceFlag>1</CertificateIssuanceFlag>
                <DeclarationTypeCode>30</DeclarationTypeCode>
                <CalculationOfTaxesDate>2020-10-06</CalculationOfTaxesDate>
                <GeneralChemistryDetails />
                <DeliveryDetails>
                    <TransportVehicleIdentificationNumber>K4423NBA</TransportVehicleIdentificationNumber>
                    <TransportVehicleCountry>BG</TransportVehicleCountry>
                    <NationalTransportMode>3</NationalTransportMode>
                </DeliveryDetails>
                <ClearingAgent>
                    <ClearingAgentType>1</ClearingAgentType>
                    <ClearingAgentEORI>GR1234567</ClearingAgentEORI>
                </ClearingAgent>
            </ExciseTaxesDeclaration>
            <ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignor>
                <ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignorType>0</ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignorType>
            </ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignor>
            <ExciseTaxesObligee>
                <ObligeeType>7</ObligeeType>
                <ObligeeIdentificationType>1</ObligeeIdentificationType>
                <ObligeeIdentification>1234567</ObligeeIdentification>
                <ContactDetails />
            </ExciseTaxesObligee>
            <ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignee>
                <ConsigneeType>0</ConsigneeType>
                <ConsigneeIdentificationType>1</ConsigneeIdentificationType>
                <ConsigneeIdentification>1234567</ConsigneeIdentification>
                <ContactDetails />
                <SpecialConsignee>
                    <SpecialConsigneeLicenseType>1</SpecialConsigneeLicenseType>
                </SpecialConsignee>
                <VesselRegistrationDetails>
                    <VesselRegistrationType>1</VesselRegistrationType>
                </VesselRegistrationDetails>
            </ExciseTaxesDeclarationConsignee>
            <ExciseTaxesRow>
                <ExciseTaxesDeclarationRowNumber>1</ExciseTaxesDeclarationRowNumber>
                <SymbolNumbers>ΔΙΠΛΟΚΑΜΠΙΝΟ ΦΟΡΤΗΓΟ FORD RANGER ΚΥΛ:2500  ΕΤΟΥΣ:2007</SymbolNumbers>
                <TaricCode>8704219900</TaricCode>
                <TaricAdditionCode>1901</TaricAdditionCode>
                <TaxQuantity>1</TaxQuantity>
                <CountryOfOrigin>SE</CountryOfOrigin>
                <GrossWeight>3020.000</GrossWeight>
                <NetWeight>3020.000</NetWeight>
                <ConditionIdentification>48</ConditionIdentification>
                <PreviousConditionIdentification>00</PreviousConditionIdentification>
                <ExemptionCode>P12</ExemptionCode>
                <StatisticalValue>6600.00</StatisticalValue>
                <SupplementaryComputationInformation>
                    <SupplementaryComputationInfo>816       </SupplementaryComputationInfo>
                    <SupplementaryComputationValue>6600.00</SupplementaryComputationValue>
                </SupplementaryComputationInformation>
                <PreviousDocuments>
                    <PreviousDocumentType>4</PreviousDocumentType>
                    <PreviousAsdeDocument />
                    <PreviousEaadDocument />
                    <PreviousStampRequestDocument />
                    <PreviousVehicleArrivalDocument>
                        <DeclarationReferenceNumber>19GRVA44531810</DeclarationReferenceNumber>
                    </PreviousVehicleArrivalDocument>
                    <PreviousVehicleMovementDocument />
                    <PreviousExciseTaxesDeclarationDocument />
                </PreviousDocuments>
                <ReferenceDocuments>
                    <ReferenceDocumentId>1E04</ReferenceDocumentId>
                    <ReferenceDocumentNumber>2048764105</ReferenceDocumentNumber>
                </ReferenceDocuments>
                <ReferenceDocuments>
                    <ReferenceDocumentId>1E05</ReferenceDocumentId>
                    <ReferenceDocumentNumber>1018744363</ReferenceDocumentNumber>
                </ReferenceDocuments>
                <ReferenceDocuments>
                    <ReferenceDocumentId>3</ReferenceDocumentId>
                    <ReferenceDocumentNumber>969/2019</ReferenceDocumentNumber>
                </ReferenceDocuments>
                <ReferenceDocuments>
                    <ReferenceDocumentId>4</ReferenceDocumentId>
                    <ReferenceDocumentNumber>2593/2018</ReferenceDocumentNumber>
                </ReferenceDocuments>
                <ReferenceDocuments>
                    <ReferenceDocumentId>1</ReferenceDocumentId>
                    <ReferenceDocumentNumber>14.03.2019</ReferenceDocumentNumber>
                </ReferenceDocuments>
                <VehicleDetails>
                    <FrameNumber>WF1053539371</FrameNumber>
                    <CarKind>8</CarKind>
                    <ImporterCodeOrBrandName>13</ImporterCodeOrBrandName>
                    <FirstAllowanceDate>2007-12-18</FirstAllowanceDate>
                    <VehicleFactoryType>2AW</VehicleFactoryType>
                    <VehicleUsedFlag>1</VehicleUsedFlag>
                    <EngineCapacity>2500</EngineCapacity>
                    <EngineType>WL</EngineType>
                    <FuelType>ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΟ</FuelType>
                    <MakeYear>2007</MakeYear>
                    <VehicleModelName>RANGER</VehicleModelName>
                    <ImportedDate>2019-02-19</ImportedDate>
                    <CountryLast>SE</CountryLast>
                    <MileageType>456</MileageType>
                    <CarbonDioxideEmissionsType>456</CarbonDioxideEmissionsType>
                    <VehicleRebateFlag>0</VehicleRebateFlag>
                </VehicleDetails>
                <TaxComputation>
                    <NationalAccountingCode>504</NationalAccountingCode>
                    <SuspensionFlag>0</SuspensionFlag>
                    <AmountOfTaxes>686.4</AmountOfTaxes>
                    <PaymentMethodCode>H</PaymentMethodCode>
                    <TaxBase>6600.00</TaxBase>
                    <TaxRate>10,4000</TaxRate>
                </TaxComputation>
                <SpecialMentions />
            </ExciseTaxesRow>
        </DeclarationOfExciseTaxesRegistration>
    </Body>
</EF15A>
```

Comment: Did you import the WSDL in SoapUI and let it generate a request ? What does that look like ? The error looks like some business rule, not WSDL specific.

Comment: @ou_ryperd Yes Id did. I add it in my question as edit

Comment: Did you read the [manual](https://portal.gsis.gr/icisnetcms/getFile?ClazzName=com.unisystems.icisnet.cms.Instructions&UID=10400143&MemberName=Upload) (PDF) for that service. The security mechanism is described in there.

Comment: @ou_ryperd this link doesnt work . It shows 500 Internal Server Error. The weird part is that when I send from my program messageType "IMP_ID015","ECS_ED15" and some other it works fine. When I try to send the "EMCS_EF15" message it gives me that error. It seems to ask the SubmittingTraderIdentification  as parameter and not as variable inside XML. If I upload the generated XML from my program in their platform it works fine, so I suppose it's not something from XML but from wrong credentials or additional parameters for the specified messagetype

Comment: the link gives me a pdf to download.

Comment: For me it gives me error 500 Internal Server Error

Servlet error: Database error occured: ORA-31001: Invalid resource handle or path name "/public/APPLICATION/com.unisystems.icisnet.cms.Instructions.Upload.10400143.GR.pdf" .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222187/discussion-between-ou-ryperd-and-rippergr).

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem with EF15 submission through web service.
SubmittingTraderIdentification is never passed even if it is completed inside the xml message.
Greek custom authorities have not an explanation for this problem.
Our customers manually upload ef15 xml file

Comment: I spoke with them many times and send them email and soap messages. The answer is the same as yours. They told me that other programs work fine ,which I doubt because I can send import & export messages just fine. So you believe is IcisNet problem and not from my XML message?

Comment: I added my XML in my question. Notice that I have modified so it can pass even if I send it manyally. If I stick with the original XSD it says that there is an XML error

Comment: Maybe someone in here can create a correct file with classes based on the XSD . When I try to create it in visual studio it gives me errors

Comment: I made an XML based on XSD without almost no changes and still the same error. I know a program that can send DEFK  but I don't know how they do it. It is a java application.

Comment: I saw a program that sends EF15 messages to icisnet and receive MRN without problem, but I haven't understood how he does it.